# Stack Exchange User Flair on Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

Is there a way to get the Stack Exchange user flair html snippet within my tumblr home page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Tumblr manage blog page and put in the flair html snippet into the box for sidebar content. I don't exactly remember what it was called, but if you don't find it, I'll check on it.

Comment: Found it - go to Customise > Info > add the snippet into the Description